# Как работает функция computeIfAbsent в Java

Tags: java, map, java-hashmap

Помогите разобраться со следующим кодом на Java:

```
private void loadYamlMatcher(MappingNode entry, String filename) {
        List<MappingNode> matcherConfigList = matcherConfigs
            .computeIfAbsent(filename, k -> new ArrayList<>(32));
        matcherConfigList.add(entry);
    }
```

В данном случаи в `filename` передаются последовательно следующие названия файлов:

```
Amazon
AmazonDevices
Android
AndroidDeviceOverrides
Anonymized
Apple
```

И в `matcherConfigs` они записываются в следующем порядке

```
Apple
Android
Anonymized
Amazon
AmazonDevices
AndroidDeviceOverrides
```

Вопрос заключатеся в том, почему теряется сортировка по алфавиту?

Comment: У вас matcherConfigs какой тип имеет? Могу поспорить, что HashMap

Comment: Да, вы правы он haspMap, но как это влияет на порядок? (с Java плохо знаком)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) возвращает или значение из отображения по ключу, или создает его, если его не было. Это аналог [getOrDefault](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) с разницей, который принимает функцию (например лямбду) и возвращает ее результат, а если ключа не было, то добавит

Пример:

```
Map<String, List<String>> config = new HashMap<>();

System.out.println(config.get("abc"));
// null

System.out.println(config.getOrDefault("abc", Arrays.asList("test", "log")));
System.out.println(config);
// [test, log]
// {}

System.out.println(config.computeIfAbsent("abc", k -> Arrays.asList("test", "log")));
System.out.println(config);
// [test, log]
// {abc=[test, log]}
```

А порядок у вас не такой из-за особенности реализации [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) - он хранит не ключи, а их хэши, поэтому порядок не гарантируется

Для сохранения порядка ключей по их добавлению используйте [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)